# Data is not correctly displayed on a HTML table inside a react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am working on a React component that based on some information will send an email. I created another component for that email so I can pass the data and then it will display the data in a proper format. The format includes two tables, one that is fixed and the other that is dynamic. At the moment, the dynamic table the data that I pass to it is displaying everything on the same row. I would like to have it displayed on different rows.

This is how the data is sent to the function:

```
{
"partnerPriority": [
    " A",
    " B"
],
"partnerTournament": [
    " Copa libertadores",
    "  Copa "
],
"partnerEvent": [
    " Cali vs America",
    "  Copa libertadores"
],
"partnerDate": [
    " 12/12/12",
    " 11/11/22"
],
"partnerCountries": [
    " CO,BR,EC",
    " CO"
],
"partnerChannels": [
    " ESPN,FOX",
    " FOX"
]
```

}

This is the function:

```
 export const EmailHtePartner = (data) => {
  try {

    return `
  <html>
  <head>
    <style>
      * {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      h1,
      h2,
      h4,
      h3,
      h5 {
        color: white;
      }
      h4 {
        margin: auto;
      }
      th {
        font-weight: 600;
        margin: 6;
        padding: 8;
      }
      td {
        color: white;
        margin: 6;
        padding: 8;
        font-weight: 100;
      }
      table {
        text-align: center;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      table,
      td,
      th {
        border: 0.1rem solid #ffffff;
      }
      .wrapper {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .container {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .email-content {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="email-content">
          <div
            style="
              background-color: #050914;
              border-radius: 10px;
              padding: 1.5rem;
              width: 700px;
              height: fit-content;
              margin: 3rem;
            "
          >
  
            <h2 style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center">
             TEXT
            </h2>
            <h3 style="margin: 2; font-weight: bold; text-align: center">
              Events:
            </h3>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th
                  style="
                    background-color: #fd8204;
                    color: #050914;
                    font-weight: 600;
                  "
                >
                  Category
                </th>
                <th style="background-color: #fd8204; color: #050914">
                  Tournament
                </th>
                <th style="background-color: #fd8204; color: #050914">Event</th>
                <th style="background-color: #fd8204; color: #050914">Date</th>
                <th style="background-color: #fd8204; color: #050914">
                  Countries
                </th>
                <th style="background-color: #fd8204; color: #050914">
                  Channels
                </th>
              </tr>
              ${data.map((item, index) => `
              <tr key=${index}>
                <td>${item.partnerPriority}</td>
                <td>${item.partnerTournament}</td>
                <td>${item.partnerEvent}</td>
                <td>${item.partnerDate}</td>
                <td>${item.partnerCountries}</td>
                <td>${item.partnerChannels}</td>
              </tr>
            `)}
            </table>
              <h3 style="margin: 2; font-weight: bold; text-align: center">
                Notes:
              </h3>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th style="background-color: #fd8204; color: black">
                  Partners
                </th>
                <th style="background-color: #fd8204; color: #050914">DMCR</th>
                <th style="background-color: #fd8204; color: #050914">
                  Thresholds
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td
                  style="
                    text-align: justify;
                    font-weight: 100;
                    width: 33.3%;
                    padding: 1rem;
                  "
                >
                  TEXT
                </td>
                <td
                  style="
                    text-align: justify;
                    font-weight: 100;
                    width: 33.3%;
                    padding: 1rem;
                  "
                >
                  TEXT
                </td>
                <td
                  style="
                    text-align: justify;
                    font-weight: 100;
                    width: 33.3%;
                    padding: 1rem;
                  "
                >
                  TEXT
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <div
              style="display: flex; justify-content: left; padding-top: 10px"
            >
              <h5 style="margin: 2; font-weight: 100">
                TEXT
              </h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

   `;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

When testing I see everything on the same row, however I would like the data to be on a different row such this:

```
Category,tournament,event,Date,Countries,Channels
A,Copa libertadores, Cali vs America,12/12/12,CO,BR,EC,ESPN  -> first row.
B,Copa, Copa libertadores, 11/11-22,CO,FOX -> second row.
```

If there were to be more data then as many rows as needed should be added.

Comment: can you show us the output of the html which the map() function is creating? I cant tell if this is a styling issue or not.

Comment: @SpikeThea this is what the map() is creating. 
              <tr>
                <td> A, B</td>
                <td> Copa libertadores,  Copa </td>
                <td> Cali vs America,  Copa libertadores</td>
                <td> 12/12/12, 11/11-22</td>
                <td> CO,BR,EC, CO</td>
                <td> ESPN,FOX, FOX</td>
              </tr>

Comment: I understand now. You need to reformat your Object so that you have 2 large nested objects, because you have flat CSV like data. so for example 

{}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you will be getting the same length of values for every key of the `data` object. Ideally, it should be like that because if it is table data, then the length of the values of every key inside the `data` object should be the same.

**Solution:**

```
{
  data['partnerPriority'].map((value, index) => <tr key={index}>
     <td>{data['partnerPriority'][index]}</td>
     <td>{data['partnerTournament'][index]}</td>
     <td>{data['partnerEvent'][index]}</td>
     <td>{data['partnerDate'][index]}</td>
     <td>{data['partnerCountries'][index]}</td>
     <td>{data['partnerChannels'][index]}</td>
   </tr>
)}
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://playcode.io/1718776).